# Exchange 2003 Accept and send mail from a different domain than the Active Directory domain

Tags: exchange-2003

I have an Exchange 2003 server which I have set up on domain hq.domain.com.  I would like to accept mail for domain.com and when mail is sent externally I would like it to show as from domain.com, not our actual internal Active Directory domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure your Exchange server to recieve mail for this domain. To do so, in exchange system manager, either edit the default recipient policy or create a new one. In here, add the email domain you want to recieve mail for. If you would like it to be the default domain for mail sent out, check to make it default. Assuming your DNS is configured correctly and your user accounts have the right email addresses setup, that should be all you need to do.

For more details on how to do this, take a look at [this article](http://www.petri.co.il/configure_exchange_2000_2003_to_receive_email_for_other_domains.htm).

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you add the domain.com into your accepted domains as well, as an authoritative type with default set to true. then set up the mx records on your domain.com dns.

do this before you add the default recipient policy for domain.com

Comment: accepted domains is an Exchange 2007/2010 option, it is not in Exchange 2003. Exchange 2003 only uses the recipient policies to handle what domains to accept.

Comment: ohh sorry - i overlooked the 03 part and just saw exchange.  my fault :(